# Wireguard VPN can't access non-standard ports

Tags: networking, vpn, docker, wireguard, unifi

I have a Unifi UDM-SE running a Wireguard VPN server with the following configuration:

"Main" network: 10.2.1.0/24
"Main" gateway: 10.2.1.1

VPN network: 10.2.2.0/24
VPN gateway: 10.2.2.1

Peer allowed IPs: 10.2.0.0/16

I can successfully connect and ping any service that operates on ports 80 or 443 it appears.

For example, i have a Proxmox server located at 10.2.1.100:8006, however when tunneling through the VPN, i cannot access this server through this port. However if i navigate to 10.2.1.100:80 or 10.2.1.100:443, my Truenas GUI which operates on that port, loads successfully. I can also successfully access another server i know that operates at 10.2.1.27:80. Note that specifically I am trying to access my docker services that are found at 10.2.1.183:9443-9455 (each port reflective of a different docker service)

Additionally, i can ping/access any other computer on the 10.2.1.0/24 subnet, however any services that i provide on any port other than those ports doesnt load.

Ive tried to configure static routes from my VPN gateway to hop to my "Main" gateway to no avail.

Any ideas? this is an odd one.

Comment: whatever the port issues are, they have nothing to do with wireguard

Comment: check for firewalls in between the connection; some firewall is blocking you.

Comment: Please provide your ip route and iptables config. Also do a tcpdump to get more insights what goes wrong

Comment: requested route is as follows:

10.2.2.3 (windows machine) -> 10.2.2.1 (unifi gateway) ->10.2.1.101 (proxmox) -> 10.2.1.183 (debian machine running docker) -> 172.17.0.3 (example container)

the windows machine firewall is not blocking it because i can reach other resources on the 10.2.1.0/24 subnet. 

The unifi gateway knows how to hop to 10.2.1.0/24 because i can access any other resource on it

The proxmox datacenter firewall is disabled